# Deserialize protobuf format from kafka

Tags: java, deserialization, apache-kafka, protocol-buffers

I was wondering if there are any examples for deserializing a kafka ConsumerRecord in the protobuf format to json/ string ?

I found the KafkaAvroDeserializer for Avro and was looking for an example for protobuf. 
Right now, I'm guessing I need to use the protoc compiler to create a java class from the .proto file and use it to deserialize.

Apologies if this is a duplicate.

Thanks

Comment: What you are guessing (use a code generator to generate a Java class for the proto file(s)) seems correct to me. What stops you from moving forward with that approach?

Comment: Thanks Stefan, that did work. I ran into a few issues on the way, we were using proto2 and initially I was splitting the a bigger .proto file into smaller ones and I had to rename the outer class as well as use the java options to add to generate equals and hashcode and split into multiple files so that it generated seperate classes for the Builder etc but Im finally able to deserialize back to the class object now.

Comment: This might be the help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45581082/kafka-console-consumer-sh-custom-deserializer