# kafka-console-consumer custom deserializer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I would like to use my custom `value.deserializer` when using the kafka-console-consumer command line tool.  Something like this:

```
./kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server kafka2:29092 \
                         --property value.deserializer=My.Custom.KafkaDeserializer \
                         --topic TEST
```

But its unable to find my custom class...

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: My.Custom.KafkaDeserializer

How can I reference the appropriate jar file so that the script will recognize it?

Comment: You have to add this class into the classpath. Besides, even you do so, console-consumer tool still cannot use it since it's a known bug. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-2526

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already said there is an opened JIRA for that (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-2526) and a custom deserializer can't be used yet.

Comment: I have checked `confluent-community-5.1.0-2.11`. It honors `--value-deserializer`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to place the deserializer jar under the "libs" folder of your Kafka server.